# Do I need to delete a question here to ask it on another stackexchange?

Tags: support

It was suggested that I ask [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109338/apt-get-wants-me-to-remove-packages-from-r-cran-that-i-need) at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

When I did, I got a message saying I could only post one question every 20 minutes. My last post was on stackoverflow and was over a day old. I waited at least half an hour and tried to post but the page just hung for a long time and it didn't post. I waited another half hour or so. This repeated at least three times.

I tried a different browser (first chrome, then firefox); same result. I don't have the reputation to ask a meta question on the ubuntu site. What can I do?

Comment: You don't _need_ to delete your post on SO to post on AU. It seems odd that you are getting the behavior you are seeing (page just hung for a long time)

Comment: You can also flag your own question and politely ask a moderator to migrate it to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8):

This is because there are other people on the same network as you posting questions to ubuntu.  You deleting your SO question wouldn't change a thing.

The rate limiting applies to all accounts on a particular network (below a certain reputation level) to prevent users from creating new accounts to get around rate limits.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know I don't need to delete my question.     But isn't it strange that it would hang for so long? More than an hour now. In the mean time, I've posted this question and comment and done many other things online. It's still going with that animated elipses after the word "discard".  Oh and now instead of the 20 minute message, it says "You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period."

Comment: @plamtrue The page hanging is likely a connection issue, but who knows.  As for the changing error message, it's likely the result of other people on your network continuing to ask questions.

Comment: Good idea, but I'm pretty sure it's just me . . . oh and that whacky digital ape over there. I'm gonna try Ben Voigt's advice.